# How to handle light issue in face recognition?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am trying to implement face recognition using OpenCV. I am somewhat successful in doing so. If I have more than 10 training images and walk in front of the camera right away, system can recognize me.

**But the problem is**: if my training images were taken more than 4+ hours ago (in winter), then my current images don't match with the training images, hence showing me as unknown. The most likely reason is the **light issue**.

What are the best possible ways to handle this issue? Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: which recognition techniques do you use? Did you try to "color-normalize" the images?

Comment: equalizeHist, CLAHE, bioinspired::Retina (latter being my favourite)

Comment: You can try converting them to lbp images and then train

Comment: @micka...I am using LBPH algo. Will this still work if there is substantial difference in light, in training image and the current image?
ssh99.....As I said, I am using LBPH algo, doesn't it mean the pictures are converted to LBP images automatically...or do I have to convert them explicitly?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this issue ?